# jQuery drill down menu not work with jQuery 1.8.3

Tags: jquery

I have use jQuery Drill Down Menu From http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-drill-down-menu-plugin/getting-started/.

but this plugin is only work with given jQuery Version 1.4. If i am integrate with my project where jQuery 1.8.3, it produce following error into console.

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object][rel="2"]
```

Any solution?

I don't want to add another jQuery Version just for this menu effect, it increase page sige.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not a problem.

> You can have multiple versions of jQuery in a same page using [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

Check this answer [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1566644/1671639)